# How to implement csrf with nextjs as fe and spring security application as be

Tags: next.js, spring-security

I have a project implemented with nextjs as frontend and spring boot as server. I am doing the user login/register feature. The main flow is completed, a user can send a post login request to the backend end point.
Now these two applications are in my own computer, and use different ports. The CORS mechinism is ok. If I disable csrf, all is fine. But if I enable it, the user can not send POST request success.

I have tried to add this code to spring security config like this:

```
http
    .csrf(csrf -> {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieCustomizer(cookie -> {
            cookie.sameSite("None");
            cookie.maxAge(3600L);
            cookie.httpOnly(false);
            cookie.secure(true);
            cookie.domain("localhost");
    });
```

And I can see the XSRF cookie in the browser debugging panel after send a get request:

[image]

After this GET request which get the cookie contains XSRF, I send a POST request with credentials field immediately.

```
const fetchCsrf = async () => {
        console.log("get csrf begin");
        const response = await fetch(apiEndpoint(RequestURL.csrfToken), {
            // credentials: 'include',
        });
        console.log("get csrf complete: ", await response.json());
        console.log("--- XSRF-TOKEN = ", response.headers.get("XSRF-TOKEN"));

        const response1 = await fetch("http://localhost:8081/api/auth/test", {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include",
        });
        console.log("response1 = ", await response1.json());
    }
```

As I know, the XSRF cookie should be contained by the test reqeust, but actually it doesn't.

I really don't know why. please help me.

Comment: Did you read the spring security documentation on their webpage? They have an entire chapter named ”csrf”

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes, I read this article again. I realise maybe csrf should not deliver in cookie. I watched a youtube video, he didn't provide frontend project, but I guess the csrf should pass in the post body. 
But, if every request get a new csrf in response cookie, how can I extract it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my own question and write my answer here, hope can help someone else.

The key point is when I request the csrf token when the website startup, the spring security tells me how to use it through the response.

```
@GetMapping("/csrf")
    public ResponseEntity<HTTPResponse<?>> csrfToken(HttpServletResponse response
            , CsrfToken token) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new HTTPResponse<>(token));
    }
```

Send a request to this endpoint, I get a response:

```
{
    "code": "0",
    "message": "success",
    "body": {
        "headerName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "token": "-KhhF6VGuc5Al4MmziymxHWx8TtcV5ARmdY84fBDTxyWX19Nm5BQdZRx2P5tp-AVqAGSpUXT3AM_NqI8qLcK2MV2di33Ojx1",
        "parameterName": "_csrf"
    }
}
```

In the body field, "parameterName" tells me if I can send the csrf token as a parameter of any request, and "headerName" tells me I can send the csrf within any request header with its name "headerName".

so long as spring security receive the csrf through one of these two ways, it can verify a request successfully.

In addition, every post request sent from fe needs contains `credential: "include"`. And the spring be csrf should be set as:

```
.csrf(csrf -> {
                    CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();
                    cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieCustomizer(cookie -> {
                        cookie.sameSite("None");
                        cookie.secure(true);
                        cookie.httpOnly(false);
                    });
                    csrf.csrfTokenRepository(cookieCsrfTokenRepository);
                })
```